# How to control PCIe power?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

Is there any consumer-grade motherboard (for Intel i3/i5/i7 CPUs) that lets me physically power on/off PCIe slots?

PCIe slots are on motherboards, so I guess a motherboard can easily power up/down PCIe if the manufacturer makes it so. Either a physical switch (such as jumper pins) or SW switch is fine (through a motherboard utility).

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Because he has a wonderful idea!

Comment: Some motherboards have ability to control devices like you have described, for example on my laptop if I go to device manager and look for properties under network adapter I can see Power Management tab that has option to turn off device to save power. But I'm unaware of a actual switch that you can flip your self. 
In regards to pin on the MB it would be unwise, cause you would need to open it the case every time.